# How to find whether tess-two/BUILDING done successfully or not.?

Tags: android-ndk, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

i am working on an android OCR application, for that i am using Tesseract. Therefor it is necessary to do tess-two buidling first. I actually completed tess-two building but i don't know whether tess-two building completed successfully or not.

following is the directory of tess-two after building:

[image]

Comment: How did you build tess-two? From the command line? Using ndk-build? From Android Studio? Were there any errors or message? The presence of the obj and libs directories indicates something was build, but doesn't tell us if it was built successfully.

Comment: sir i have followed this link   http://androidadvance.com/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-tessaract-ocr-in-android-android-studio/                 but this post has lack of details

Comment: Sir now i found pre-built tess-two library from this site http://androidtesstwo.blogspot.com/2014/03/making-android-ocr-app-using-tess-two.html  and succesfully imported to my android studio application. soon i will make video tutorial on it.

Comment: Good for you! Good luck on the video tutorial.

Comment: If you're using Android Studio you can also [use](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#usage) the project without having to build it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if you saw `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` in your terminal when you ran the final build step, then it did in fact complete successfully. You should have *.so files in your libs directory.

You can run the `tess-two-test` instrumented test cases to double check.